# What is the cause of the horizontal drift in the ascend path of the Starship and other rockets?

Tags: spacex-starship, celestial-mechanics, launch-trajectories, ascent, flight-profile

As can be seen in the available videos on-line and in the following picture, as the rocket ascends, a horizontal drift in its path can be seen. I have forgotten the calculation of the Coriolis effect since many years has passed, but I guess that the Coriolis effect in this range would be negligible. Am I right? If so, what is the cause of this horizontal shift? Is it intentional or caused by wind, etc.?

[image: composite snapshots of the Starship SN10 test flight path]
*Image borrowed from: https://www.jackbeyer.com/digital/sn10compdigital8*

Comment: Cool question and graphic! Can you include a link to the source of the image? *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh The lower right corner mark shows the photographer and the site. However I added a link.

Comment: *Thanks for the edit!* It's good to have it as searchable text and a url directly to the location, in addition to any embedded watermark or other text-rendered-as-images which doesn't really provide an actual link to the source: "it says `nasaspaceflight.com` in the image, but your link is to `jackbeyer.com`

Comment: @uhoh Jack Beyer works for NasaSpaceFlight but also as an independent photographer. This image is hosted on his personal website. Original idea for such composite Starship image comes from Trevor Mahlmann who first did it for SN8.

Comment: Anyone else think that flame in the 3rd-from-last airborne image is the source of the failure that led to the ultimate "relaunch event" ?

Answer (score 4):

It's quite intentional. There's a significant risk that the vehicle will fail during ascent, and then there's the transition to the "skydiver" orientation and controlled descent using the flaps which had never been tried outside of wind tunnels before these tests. They needed to have the ground impact point be somewhere reasonably safe if things went wrong, and also to test the ability of the vehicle to guide itself to the pad during the skydiver descent.

The Falcon 9 boosters similarly come down on a trajectory that requires controlled flight to bring it over to the drone ship or landing pad. This was demonstrated a couple years ago when there was a failure of the grid fin hydraulics, forcing the booster to "land" offshore.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can't find a single sentence that isn't common sense or essentially self-evident, but perhaps I don't have a critical eye. Can you identify which statements are in most need sourcing?

Comment: The Falcon 9 booster divert maneuver has been described several times over the years, including here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32590/if-the-crs16-booster-was-out-of-control-how-did-it-abort-to-water. The hop trajectory here is just an application of the same idea, with a horizontal glide back toward the pad and a sizable divert built into the flip maneuver.

Comment: @uhoh a wise person once wrote "...we believe that SE answers in science-based sites should always strive to source their facts so that readers can verify and read further. " https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1649/6944

Comment: hmm...that particular user is more of a *wiseguy* than a wise person if you ask me, but your point (though obviously poorly sourced) is well taken ;-)

Comment: @OrganicMarble [space-lawyer](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/25876/spacelawyer) has recently added three unsourced answers. It's great that they are back after an almost two year hiatus...

Comment: @uhoh must be in my ignored tags. Lawyers get *paid* to argue.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff, _thanks a lot_. Your answer sounds logical and makes sense, but I prefer a _somewhat_ official answer, i.e., an answer with a credible source. I have searched and found that, for example, wind would cause dispersions, although as the picture shows, this horizontal movement looks precise and calculated.

Comment: A directionally stable rocket will weathervane.  Since the writer mentioned "other rockets" rigorous sourcing may not be as necessary (although very useful).  In this case, since the "flop" will drift *with* the wind, it is helpful.  Still don't know why they overrotate the damn thing, especially when they have seconds to do a stabilized approach to landing.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni, mentioning the drift while flopping sounds clever. _Thank you._  *P.S.* All probable causes mentioned so far, in these comments and below other answers, make common sense and it might be that it is multifactorial, but I, for the sake of my own knowledge and out of personal curiosity, am looking for the most rigorous source.

Comment: OK, they are doing *novel* research.  There is no source (yet) (best of luck to them) (hope they get those Raptors running right soon).  The "drift" is very controllable by *gimballing* the engines, they can fly up where ever they want for whatever reason.  Its the landing that needs work, and they need to get one back whole.  I would back all the way off to a SN6 "hop" with the *3 engine* configuration, then a 10 km flight with a *vertical parachute descent* and landing (multiple times), before trying to flip and land again.  They may be having problems with their fuel and oxidizer valves.

Comment: In other words, use a *dry lake bed* (DLB) for fewer RUDs.

Answer (score 1):

According to Nasa Spaceflight's webcast, that is intentional to do the belly flop maneuver which is how it is supposed to land.

Comment: Can you add a link to the webcast and give an approximate time where the statement is made, and include a short summary or quote of the statement? Currently this is not enough to be a Stack Exchange answer post, but if you can add those then this will be a proper answer. Thanks, and *Welcome to Space!*